# Where did all the comments go on "What is a Java Interface"?

Tags: support, comments, moderation

There was a [question yesterday on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755587/what-is-a-java-interface-closed) that was deemed too trivial by some, downvoted, closed, reopened and finally closed as a duplicate.

This process was documented in moderator comments on the question.

Those comments are now gone.

How? Why?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes if there are too many comments that are just noise, a moderator will wipe them clean. This is generally considered a good thing.